# покоится ли тело или нет

Tags: python

программа которая узнает по векторам XYZ покоится ли тело я не очень в физике помогите плиз

Comment: В формулировании вопросов вы тоже не очень, к сожалению :(

Comment: в формулировке я по собственному мнению как раз очень, это вы просто не знаете физикку судя по всему, так как любой бы программист компетентный в физике смог бы понять мой вопрос,пример из моей жизни: я спросил у физика таким же вопросом изложенным выше он сразу понял меня и обьяснил но я до конца не понял,так что вы здесь не очень то и правы)

Comment: Если координаты не изменяются, значит тело покоится. Но еще может быть вращение вокруг трех осей. Вращение не очень понятно как отследить.

Comment: [я спросил у физика] Я спросил у физика где моя любимая долго физик интегралы брал за моим окном.

Comment: ладно если вы не поняли мой вопрос то вот вам ссылка на сайт где я брал задачу эту http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/69/A

Comment: А зачем вы пришли сюда, если физик вам уже объяснил?

Comment: @ Aizel "в формулировке я по собственному мнению как раз очень", нет, в  формулировке вы как раз "очень НЕ очень". Потому что в исходной задаче, на которую вы-же и дали потом ссылку, явно и однозначно написано, что "даны силы, действующие на тело". Из вашей формулировки следует - и так это поняли все отвечающие -  что заданы координаты X,Y и Z.  Так что "не спешите обвинять других в том что они  не понимают в физике.

Comment: Откуда же нам знать, какие вектора имелись в виду? Конечно препод понял, он же знает ваш уровень и проходимые темы! А мы тут не телепат, и не можем знать, идёт речь про векторы сил, где достаточно тривиальнейшей арифметики, про радиус-векторы объектов, вершин многогранников, где надо использовать полноценное моделирование гравитационного взаимодействия и сил трения, или даже векторы координат и скоростей квантовых частиц, из которых состоит тело, или что ещё.
Если вы видите лишь одно возможное значение этого описания, это возможно показывает не точность ваших слов, а ограниченность познаний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В первой строке задано натуральное число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100), далее
>   следует n строк по три целых числа в каждой: координата xi, координата
>   yi и координата zi вектора силы, приложенной к телу
>   ( - 100 ≤ xi, yi, zi ≤ 100).
>
> входные данные
>   3
>   3 -1 7
>   -5 2 -4
>   2 -1 -3
>
> выходные данные YES

Ну, это проще.

Для этого примера - сумма координат векторов силы по каждой оси равна нулю, поэтому тело покоится.

3+(-5)+2=0
(-1)+2+(-1)=0
7+(-4)+(-3)=0

Для другого примера (он первый в задании) суммы не равны нулю, поэтому тело движется.